# how can i excute this cURL with Ktor Client For Kotlin-multiplatform?

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

curl -X POST 
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ehUKQVObBspFk0MBFNSSg3MwLJofpeoFtDhQNIgS" 
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 9HNNfwY6ITbUGqsfMSJS3OlQVqYfm5EAiZWVe012" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{ "file_type":"A string","encryption_tool_id":"A string","user_id":"A string","query":"A string" }" 
https://encyriptionapp.b4a.io/classes/UserFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {}

client.post<String>("https://encyriptionapp.b4a.io/classes/UserFiles") {
    headers.append("X-Parse-Application-Id", "ehUKQVObBspFk0MBFNSSg3MwLJofpeoFtDhQNIgS")
    headers.append("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "9HNNfwY6ITbUGqsfMSJS3OlQVqYfm5EAiZWVe012")
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    body = """
        { "file_type":"A string","encryption_tool_id":"A string","user_id":"A string","query":"A string" }
    """.trimIndent()
}
```

Also, you can use the [JsonFeature](https://ktor.io/docs/json.html) for serializing objects to JSON.